# Which .net math function always rounds up

Tags: c#

If I have a number, I would like it to output a rounded up number, like this:

```
1.12 = 2

1.30 = 2

0.89 = 1
```

Using `Math.Round` I was only able to get it to round up when it was over half.

Comment: Math.Ceiling https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @GrawCube The response is duplicated, but the question is not. That question was about round to nearest (Math.Round)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Math.Ceiling should do the trick.

> Returns the smallest integral value that is greater than or equal to
>   the specified double-precision floating-point number.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double temp1 = 1.12;
        double temp2 = 1.30;
        double temp3 = 0.89;

        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(temp1));
        //2
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(temp2));
        //2
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(temp3));
        //1

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Math.Ceiling` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Math.Ceiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.math.ceiling.aspx) for that

```
double dbl = Math.Ceiling(1.1); // 2
```

Note that

```
double dbl = Math.Ceiling(-1.1); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Math.Ceiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the smallest integral value that is greater than or equal to the specified  number.

```
int num = (int)Math.Ceiling(1.12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Math.Ceiling.
It will always round up :)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx